# Problems with Lumen 5.2

Tags: laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

I recently installed Laravel 5.2 and i´ve been experiencing some problems loading css and js files from the project public folder.
I have all my views on the resources folder and my asset files on the public folder, i tried installing html collective but is not working.
Could someone please help me link the css and js files, so they load.

This is my view:

```
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css" />
```

Comment: Are you looking for the [`asset`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#urls) helper to get the paths correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asset helper:

```
$url = asset('img/photo.jpg');
```

Cf docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset